# create dynamic template for joomla 1.5

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla1.7

there are tutorials on the web about gow to create index.html, css file and template.xml that contain placeholders. ok, i got it, it's simple. but i need a template that has some different views. for example:
-all pages have a topmenu, header, left sidebar, mainarea and a footer but:
-first page has no header .topmenu after which sidebar, mainarea and footer comes.
-second page has sidebar moved from left to right
-third page has four blocks (blocks for special offers) instead of mainarea.

as far as i can see, i need to create three standalone templates with unique set of placeholders for each template. because i can't see the way to change laarge mainarea placeholder with four placeholders for offers blocks on some pages. dynamically.

is there if-statements in joomla templates to simply determine a document id to view four placeholders instead of mainarea. or to not show header on the main page (f.e. doc. id="mainpage")

but i want it to be selectable like:
-this page has first case of that template (index_1.php)
-and that page has a second case of the same template (index_2.php)
like a selectbox.
is that possible?

Comment: Firstly, why are you using Joomla 1.5? You should be using 2.5 or 3.x. Have you not tried downloading a simple template and editing the structure to what you need? I'm very confused as to what you require to be honest.

Comment: @Lodder i'm also agreed with lodder

Comment: As Lodder had said, using 1.5 - why?  It's out of date and is no longer supported.  Use something newer.  In Joomla - inside the modules you can choose what to display where and on what pages.  You don't have to do that through the templates index.php.  Index.php just outlines where your modules (blocks) will show up should you choose to publishing things to them.  Which pages they are displayed on is handled through the module options.  Judging by your use of the word 'blocks' I'm assuming you're more familiar with Drupal?

Comment: simply: i cant change tha platform because of the customer's choise. the website is an old thing, and i should just refresh it. i don't wanna be a webmaster for him.

Comment: modules. if i can choose which module to show where and which to not show - it seems to be a perfect solution. and index.php contains all the placeholders at once. ok, i'll try this out.

Comment: no. i am not familiar with drupal. i like mod-x, GS cms and pure php/python. but customer wants thre-viewed template on anold joomla website.

Comment: You'll notice under modules: it will say something like "display on the following pages" (or something to that effect), you can specify the pages there.  So if you have an article (page) that is "about us", you can have certain modules only show on that page and not show on other pages, etc.  I'm pretty sure that's what you're looking for.

Comment: 2Hanny: Yeah! Positions of modules plus ability to select a page where it will be shown should do the trick. now i need to clarify where to put an usual article while all the unique blocks will be represented by html-modules. thank you Hanny !

Comment: I've added it as an answer to your question - so you can flag it as the answer.  That way if others are having the same problem they know they can look here for an answer.  Cheers.

Comment: As the developer, you should tell you client all about how outdated J1.5 is, the security risk etc. They will most likely have idiots trying to hack their site and wonder why.

Comment: @Lodder ok, ok. it actually do not belong to the question. may be i'll update two of his websites (third is on GS made by me from scratch) to joomla 1.7 or higher, but it's not my fault he prefer to stay where he is. and of course i told him that outdated joomla is not good. he is a salesmanager, he doesn't care.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will make this an answer as opposed to a comment since I believe it will do what you are looking for.

Once your articles are setup and your links to them are established (the site has the info on it you're looking for), you can create the modules containing the data that you want shown from time to time.

Go to the module manager - on the right you should see 'module assignment' or something along the lines of 'display this module on the following pages'; you can then pick which pages you want the module to show on.  You can specify all pages, none, specific pages, however you want.

This will enable you to show them only where needed however you like.
You can ALSO do this programatically inside the module (if you do custom HTML and use an extension like Sourcerer to add PHP to the module) with PHP should you want a little more flexibility, but just choosing the pages to show on should work for what you're doing.

Comment: i cant stand this. i cant make inline jdocs includes. i cant create links in menu to modules, not to an article. i cant create a really complex template. shits. i'll do that in modx or i'll give it up. joomla is just a crap.

Comment: @remort - Joomla is not crap, you just need to take the time to understand it more. If you want to link a menu item to a module (no component) then you can display the module in an article and link the menu to that article. How did I find that out the first time? Simply by using Google. If you can't create a menu item linking to an article then either your Joomla site is screwed up or your template is, it's not the Joomla system itself. Joomla is a very flexible CMS but like most people, you need to research your issues before assuming it can't be done and judging it